# Change the default search for lists from "This list" to "This site" in MOSS 2007

Tags: search, sharepoint-server

We have SharePoint 2007 and we got a request from a user to change the default behavior of the search box from **"This list** to **This site** instead. The default for the list "This list" and users can select the drop down menu to select "This site" but we need the default for specific list to show This site" instead of "This list".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If this is only for a single list, I would just add a content editor Web part  on the page and use javascript to modify the selected option in the drop down list with the search scopes.

Unfortunately I do not have access to SP right now to give you the required code but it is pretty basic.